# Lightroom: Custom Camera Profile Appears as "Unnamed Profile"

Tags: lightroom, post-processing, color-management

I'm running Lightroom CC on a macbook pro with Yosemite.

I used the X-Rite Colorchecker Passport to create a custom color profile in lightroom. Everything worked fine, except after restarting Lightroom CC, the profile in the calibration panel appears as "untitled profile."

If I check the camera profile folder in finder, the profile appears with the name that I gave it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odd. Perhaps if you move it out of the folder, then restart Lr, and verify it's gone from the menu. Then add it back in, restart Lr, and see if it picks it up. Perhaps Lr accessed it before it got named.